# MongoDB query fast in mongo shell but slow/times out in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The following query takes approximately 54ms in the mongo shell, but times out after a minute in the nodejs driver:

```
db.posts.find(
  {
    parentId: 10,
    modifiedGmt: {
      "$gte": new Date("2017-01-01T00:00:00.000z")
    },
    postType: {
      "$in": ["type1", "type2"]
    }
  },
  {
    _id: 1,
    parentId: 1,
    postId: 1,
    url: 1,
    modifiedGmt: 1,
    authors: 1,
    taxonomy: 1,
    postType: 1
  }
).sort({modifiedGmt: 1}).limit(2400)
```

Explain shows that the query is using existing indexes. If I drop the limit to something very low like 10, it won't time out but it will take far, far too long. I'm not really sure where to go with this. It's a large collection but with the indexes in place and the limit sub-10000 I don't see why it would be so slow.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to include more details in your question post - the explain results, the number of documents in collection, what indexes are created and a sample document with relevant fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suspecting that the `.sort` is not able to use your index.

I would recommend to have a read on this page [sort-operator-and-performance](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#-sort-operator-and-performance).

Comment: Turns out the sort in my code had a typo in the field name, so I was sorting on a non-existent field. Figured it out when I went to add an additional field to see about matching the index better. Thanks!